# Classification using R in a data set with numeric and categorical variables

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

I'm working on a very big data-set.(csv)

The data set is composed from **both numeric and categorical columns**.

One of the columns is my "target column" , meaning i want to use the other columns to determine which value (out of 3 possible known values) is likely to be in the "target column". In the end check my classification vs the real data.

My question:

I'm using R.

I am trying to find a way to select the subset of features which give the best classifiation.
going over all the subsets is impossible.

Does anyone know an algorithm or can think of a way do it on R?

Comment: Please give an example of your data frame, e.g. with `head(df)` or `dput(df[1:10,])`. Without, a recommendation for a algorithm that returns random values would be just as good as any other. :p

Comment: If you have a lot of variables and you want a parsimoneous model then use elasticnet (lasso, ridge) and the R package `glmnet`.

Comment: head(df) and dput() gives mush more output than is possible to place here. basically the dats is set is 115,910 lines and 87 columns, part numeric and part categorical.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a classification problem. Without knowing the amount of covariates you have for your target, can't be sure, but wouldn't a neural network solve your problem?

You could use the **nnet package**, which uses a Feed-forward neural network and works with multiple classes. Having categorical columns is not a problem since you could just use factors.

Without a datasample I can only explain it just a bit, but mainly using the function:

```
newNet<-nnet(targetColumn~ . ,data=yourDataset, subset=yourDataSubset [..and more values]..)
```

You obtain a trained neural net. What is also important here is the size of the hidden layer which is a tricky thing to get right. As a rule of thumb it should be roughly 2/3 of the amount of imputs + amount of outputs (3 in your case).

Then with:

```
myPrediction <- predict(newNet, newdata=yourDataset(with the other subset))
```

You obtain the predicted values. About how to evaluate them, I use the ROCR package but currently only supports binary classification, I guess a google search will show some help.

If you are adamant about eliminate some of the covariates, using the cor() function may help you to identify the less caracteristic ones.

*Edit for a step by step guide:*

Lets say we have this dataframe:

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: num  1 2 3 4 5
 $ b: num  1 1.5 2 2.5 3
 $ c: Factor w/ 3 levels "blue","red","yellow": 2 2 1 2 3
```

The column *c* has 3 levels, that is, 3 type of values it can take. This is something done by default by a dataframe when a column has strings instead of numerical values.

Now, using the columns *a* and *b* we want to predict which value *c* is going to be. Using a neural network. The nnet package is simple enough for this example. If you don't have it installed, use:

```
install.packages("nnet")
```

Then, to load it:

```
require(nnet)
```

after this, lets train the neural network with a sample of the data, for that, the function

portion<-sample(1:nrow(df),0.7*nrow(df))

will store in portion, 70% of the rows from the dataframe. Now, let's train that net! I recommend you to check the documentation for the nnet package with `?nnet` for a deeper knowledge. Using only basics:

```
myNet<-nnet( c~ a+b,data=df,subset=portion,size=1)
```

`c~ a+b` is the formula for the prediction. You want to predict the column *c* using the columns a and b
`data=` means the data origin, in this case, the dataframe df
`subset=` self explanatory 
`size=` the size of the hidden layer, as I said, use about 2/3 of the total columns(a+b) + total outputs(1)

We have trained net now, lets use it.

Using `predict` you will use the trained net for new values.

```
newPredictedValues<-predict(myNet,newdata=df[-portion,])
```

After that, newPredictedValues will have the predictions.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i guess i should have said that i'm very new to R- Basically learning it from scratch. (Even actions such as converting columns on the data set to factors are challenging). That is my most of the answer is beyond me. More than just a solution to the described problem, i am in need of one that is relatively easy to implement. sorry for not mentioned it before, is there a "friendlier" way to do it?

Comment: This is actually a easy approach even with all that jumbo-words, I'm also quite new to R but I've been tinkering a bit. I'll try to edit the comment for a more step-by-step guide.

Comment: Edited now, just let me know if is still not understandable, explaining myself is not one of my best assets...

Comment: o.k, i tried to use it and some questions do raise:
1. technical issue: runing -sample resulted in an error: 
"Error in -sample : invalid argument to unary operator."
I omitted the "-sample" and used 
newPredictedValues<-predict(myNet,newdata=df)
just to get the feeling of how the output looks like.
2. The results left me quite baffled, a table with cells values between 0 and 1.
I'm not sure what am I to make of it, and not sure if it got me closer to solve the question:
which subset of features is best for classification.

thanks for your patience.

Comment: I'm afraid I have explained myself wrongly. This doesn't chooses a subset of features for classification. This is actually a classification. I'll check why you get a binary classification instead of a multiple class one. The values between 0-1 should be 0-2, and the closer to a class value[0,1,2] the most likely to be part of it.

About the sample problem, my bad, it should be -portion instead of -sample, edited in the answer.

Comment: o.k great it works!! the values are between 0-1 but i think it is o.k. It is indeed the probability that an observation belongs to the class. I guess i should try to classify multiple times, each time using a different set of featuers, and somehow evaluate the results (1.not sure how yet how to do it?). 2. is there there a way to determine the portion myself ( take lines 1 to .... ), 3. can i control the method used for classification?

Comment: And another thing regarding the evaluation: The prediction I used gives probability and not a single decision about where the observation belongs. Isn't that a problem when we want to evaluate the prediction? Don't manage to find an evaluation function that matches. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have both numerical and categorical data, then you may try SVM.

I am using SVM and KNN on my numerical data and I also tried to apply DNN. DNN is pretty slow for training especially big data in R. KNN does not need to be trained, but is used for numerical data. And the following is what I am using. Maybe you can have a look at it.

```
#Train the model
y_train<-data[,1] #first col is response variable
x_train<-subset(data,select=-1) 
train_df<-data.frame(x=x_train,y=y_train)
svm_model<-svm(y~.,data=train_df,type="C")

#Test 
y_test<-testdata[,1]
x_test<-subset(testdata,select=-1)
pred<-predict(svm_model,newdata = x_test)
svm_t<-table(pred,y_test)
sum(diag(svm_t))/sum(svm_t) #accuracy
```